# How to programatically restore a recycle bin item

Tags: c++, winapi, recycle-bin

I would like to restore a deleted file from the Windows recycle bin. I have access to the original file path before deletion and the path of the recycle bin entry. How can I restore the deleted file programmatically using the Windows C++ API? Bonus points if I can restore it to a different path as well.

```cpp
// The path of the file before it was deleted
wchar_t const *original_path = L"C:\\code\\swan\\ignore\\dir_2\\file1";

// The path of the generated recycle bin entry upon deletion
wchar_t const *recycle_bin_path = L"C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-21-738277947-893724712-3765747123-1001\\$RJB4I8F";

// TODO: restore `recycle_bin_path` to `original_path`
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110901-00/?p=9753

Comment: The legend himself. Thanks Raymond, I'll give it a try

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, @Raymond  (Love your stuff ❣️)

Comment: _Maybe you want to restore files that were deleted while you were drunk_ 

Comment: _If being drunk isn’t your thing, then substitute some other form of impaired judgment_ - so now we know :)

Comment: The link Raymond gave shows how to restore an item once you find it. Also see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110830-00/?p=9773 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110831-00/?p=9763, which show how to determine the file path of each item so you can decide which one you want

Answer (score 0):

According to Raymond Chen's recommendations:

You could written a function called `WantToRestoreThisItem` which studies the properties of a Recycle Bin item and determines whether you want to restore it.

For more details you could refer to the Blog: [Invoking commands on items in the Recycle Bin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110901-00/?p=9753)